# WinDbg and Visual Studio Express editions

Tags: c#, debugging, windbg

Can WinDbg can be used together with the [Visual C# 2008 Express Edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_C.23_Express)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

windbg isn't really an IDE debugger; it is more commonly used directly on compiled exes on the machine. As such, yes, it should be OK to use with an exe *compiled* with Express Edition, but no: there is no direct involvement *of* Express Edition in this.

Ultimately, the Express, Pro, Team etc products all use the same compiler that can be used at the command line (`csc` - although they might access it more directly than the exe!).

Look also at "SOS" (Son Of Strike)

Answer (score 2):

Good question.

VS C# 2008 Express Edition contains a managed debugger.
You will most likely run into some issues running both Windbg and VS2008 Managed Debugger against the same process.

Things you may experience are breaks, and access violations within Windbg that are typically handled just fine without the presence of a native debugger.

As long as you don't intent to perform simultaneous native and managed debugging (with different debuggers) you can attach Windbg in **non-invasive mode** to a process that is running under a managed debugger without any issues.

Here is a link to some additional inforamtion on ICordbg
([Partition of ICorDebug](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2006/01/04/icordebug_overview.aspx))

Thanks,
Aaron